# transform set of parameterized generic types into one generic type parameterized with disjunction of parameters from original set of generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

how to define function `covert` from the example below?

```js
const result: BoxType<{
  name: "foo",
  value: FooType
} | {
  name: "bar",
  value: BarType
}> = /* --> */ convert<{
  foo: FooType,
  bar: BarType
}>({
  foo: BoxType<FooType>(),
  bar: BoxType<BarType>()
}) /* <-- */
```

i could to come up with something like this

```js
type Input<T> = {[type in keyof T]: BoxType<T[type]>}
type Output<T> = BoxType<{type: keyof T, value: T[keyof T]}>

function convert<T>(input: Input<T>): Output<T> {
  /* ... */
}
```

but `Output` type is obviously invalid. is it even feasible? :)

Comment: What is `BoxType`?  Is it a type or a function?  What is `MyType`?  Is the property named `name` or `type`?  Please consider making this code a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE, preferably something you yourself have tested to make sure that you are asking what you intend to ask.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlpLXN) meet your needs?  If so, I'll write up an answer explaining it.  If not, please edit the question to clarify what you're looking for.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz that's precisely what i need, thank you

Comment: @jcalz `MyType` was meant to be `BoxType`, sorry for confusion. i am interested to see your explanation. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have some definitions like this:

```
interface BoxType<T> { box: T }
interface FooType { foo: string }
interface BarType { bar: string }
declare function BoxType<T>(): BoxType<T>;
```

we can give the `convert()` function the following call signature:

```
declare function convert<T extends object>(
  input: { [K in keyof T]: BoxType<T[K]> }
): BoxType<{ [K in keyof T]-?: { name: K, value: T[K] } }[keyof T]>;
```

which I think behaves the way you want:

```
const result = convert({
  foo: BoxType<FooType>(),
  bar: BoxType<BarType>()
})

/*
const result: BoxType<{
    name: "foo";
    value: FooType;
} | {
    name: "bar";
    value: BarType;
}>
*/
```

---

The `convert()` function is generic in `T`, an object type never directly used as either the input or output, but looks like the type of `input` with "unboxed" properties.  We can define the `input` type in terms of `T` as a straightforward [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). `{[K in keyof T]: BoxType<T[K]> }`, where we "box" each property.  Since the type of `input` maps over `keyof T`, this is considered a "homomorphic" mapped type and the compiler can [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) `T` from `input`. So far this is the same as what you have.

---

For the return type of the function, we want to take each property key `K` in `keyof T` and produce the union of `{ name: K, value: T[K] }`.  In your code you took the union first before mapping.  But the type `{name: keyof T, value: T[keyof T]}` allows all sorts of undesirable values where `name` comes from one key and `value` from another.  To keep them separate, we need to iterate over each key `K` in `keyof T`, and one easy way to do that is with another mapped type like `{[K in keyof T]: {name: K, value: T[K]}}`.

Of course this type looks like `{foo: {name: "foo", value: FooType}, bar: {name: "bar", value: BarType}}`... the property value types are what we want to get the union of and we don't want keys at all.  Luckily here we can just [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `keyof T` to produce the union of property value types.  Hence  `{[K in keyof T]: {name: K, value: T[K]}}[keyof T]`.

And finally we wrap that in `BoxType`: `BoxType<{ [K in keyof T]: { name: K, value: T[K] }}[keyof T]>`.  All done!  Wait, oops, the only difference between that and the above output type is that we [modify](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) the properties of the mapped type by making sure they are not optional: `BoxType<{ [K in keyof T]-?: { name: K, value: T[K] } }[keyof T]>`  This prevents pesky `undefined` values from creeping in if your input type `T` happens to have optional properties.  And now we're done.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHMFcFMGdYJYDtygIYCMD2kAupcALBWAKGV2gCcAzNAY2lACEsAPAFQE8AHaAHg4A+UAG9Q2NgC5QHUAF9ySSrQZMAYlizc+Y0DS0zYuKslSKK1OoxZoqOpuIx2jJswtIATaPQA2dphpIJHpcBCwkFnYHQSEACgBKGVZOXgFhAG5SLx9-KkDg0PDI+giAN2pcQVBoNkokT1hQLAwAKx9ceNJQUGQePBlxAG0AaV7IgGtoLiwaWQBdZOi0wVH5kUUkqNS+fmGx5FApmbmOeYBaAH5B0CQ0AFtoGRGAGlAytF8YGQ41hQUhsdZgshFlSKUkMZQPlYJBfPgALygCEVKi4OKibr6QzbGKabRpeIJF5Y5xUJY7ATMOwOImkeQJbLAABU4IiUJhcNwFJimJ6PTujxkACIDFhhVl+e9Pt9QPiHFl5KAAD5iLECh5PUDCskS9XSr5a6n2NKKoSkZnAUhAA)